# Slow speed on Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller - HP Pavilion 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, networking, speed

I recently upgraded my internet speed to 90 mbs but when I run a speedtest on my computer, it never gets over 50 mbs. I've had the ISP company over here a few times, they've tested everything and have shown that the internet speed is in fact 90 mbs and sometimes even 100 mbs but their thought is that my ethernet and wireless ports on my HP can't accept or run at those faster speeds. Also, just to confirm my speed, I connected the ethernet to a dell laptop  and sure enough, it's running at the 90 and 100 mbs.

I've tried playing around with the settings on the network adapter Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller, adjusting to auto, 100/Full Duplex, 100/Half Duplex, 10/full, 10/half but my internet speed never changes. So, is there a setting or some other update for this issue?

Comment: Could you go to device manager, right click your network card, select properties, then go to details tab. In the drop down box, can you put here what it says. So that we could identify which type of Realtek controller it really is.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately i believe the problem is with the realtek controller. i connected an external usb wireless dongle into my laptop and the speed instantly matched up with the ethernet cable. i've searched the internet but have not found any fix. next time i won't buy anything with realtek on it!

Comment: Realtek is fine you just have a 10/100/1000 port